# "No protocol specified" when running a sudo/su app on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ireport

I try to run the iReport 5.6 on Ubuntu and Java 7, using the command:

```
$ sudo iReport-5.6.0/bin/ireport
No protocol specified.
```

I get an error. When I try run it without `sudo`, I get a permission denied error and an alert that the file Preferences on Default System are read only.

Answer (score 21):

Newer systems by design don't allow graphical applications as root (it's a Wayland thing). Workaround:

```
xhost si:localuser:root

sudo   your-graphical-app
```

Restore the default permissions:

```
xhost -si:localuser:root
```

Comment: Indeed, I tried selecting "GNOME on Xorg" at GDM login (instead of the default Wayland), and GUI apps for root started working as before.

Comment: This worked for me with Balena's Etcher AppImage on Sway (running Ubuntu 20.10).

Answer (score 9):

It looks like either the display port is not opened in your system or it is disabled.
Try running this command as non-root user:

```
xhost +
```

and then run the app with root.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sudo` with GUI using the options `-sE`, as follows:

`sudo -sE GUI_CMD`

For example, if you want to run `nemo` as root:

`sudo -sE nemo`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you installed the program under the root. X-server (graphical shell) from you has been released from your user. When you say under the root of the program run it sees that the X=server under the user's root are not running and informs you about this.

run a second copy of Xorg from the root

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108784/running-gui-application-as-another-non-root-user