# How can I get pynput working with ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, keyboard, pynput

I'm trying to get pynput working on linux (ubuntu) but I just can't get it to work. I'm running my script on a terminal window on the desktop.

I've installed pynput but just it just won't detect my keystrokes. Here's the code that I'm using from my main script:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller 
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press():
   print("key detected: " + str(key.char)))

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
```

I've tried:

- "sudo pip3 install web3"
- "sudo pip3 install pynput"
- "sudo pip3 install xlib"
- "DISPLAY=:0.0 python3 -c 'import pynput'"
- "xhost +"

And executing my script:

- "sudo python3 myscript.py"
- "python3 myscript.py"

But none of that seems to work regardless of running as root or not.

I do however get `Xlib.xauth: warning, no xauthority details available`, idk if that's causing the issue?

Any advice is appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
pip install pynput none
```

or you can use `--user` ,and install the files into your home directory to fix this. So, try executing the command

```
pip install pynput user
```

Answer (score -1):

I encounted similiar problem, and found this link useful. ["No protocol specified" when running a sudo/su app on Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833451/no-protocol-specified-when-running-a-sudo-su-app-on-ubuntu-linux)

**Newer systems by design don't allow graphical applications as root** (it's a Wayland thing). Workaround:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).